# www.example.com not redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

When we enter `example.com` in browser address bar it will redirecting to `https://example.com` and also inner pages working (redirecting to `https` site),

#### Issue 1:

When we enter `www.example.com` in browser address bar  it is not redirecting to `https://www.example.com` and Site loading without `https`,  but inner pages are redirecting to `https`

#### Issue 2:

`https://example.com/file.php` shows current content, but `http://www.example.com/file.php` shows old content, We checked in Incognito mode and clearing the caches

#### Issue 3: (this may be the root cause of the issues)

When we are seeing the `$_SERVER` parameters by accessing the url `http://www.example.com/server.php` shows `HTTPS` value as `on`

We `print_r` the `$_SERVER` in `server.php` file

#### Environment:

1. Godaddy VPS Server
2. Apache 2.3.1 (`mod_rewrite` enabled)
3. PHP 5.4.45
4. Wordpress
5. Valid SSL Certificate Configured - Required Ports are opened (80, 443)

#### In Wordpress Settings,

we placed `https` address for both `Site url` and `Home page url` as `https://example.com`

#### we used the below code in `.htaccess` for redirection

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

#### And we also checked in below sites and they are showing positive response for `SSL`

`https://www.sslshopper.com`, `whynopadlock.com`

#### Everytime We checked by clearing cache and cookies

#### DNS Records:

A (Host)

1. Host `@` Points To `xx.xx.xx.xx` with TTL `600 Seconds`

CName (Alias)

1. Host `www` Points To `@` with TTL `1 Hour`

Please suggest how can i resolve this issue with `www.example.com` to `https`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using below code in .htaccess file to redirect http request to https.

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MSIE/[1-8]\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: We tried this code, and it is working for Subpages, but not for Home Page (`www.example.com`), can you please suggest?

Comment: try to add a line: RewriteRule .* - [L,F]

Answer (score 0):

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.%{HTTP_HOST}** is an invaild condition and it never returns true because you can not use server variable in RewriteCond's pattern. You can use Regex based pattern like the following :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example.com$
```

Comment: Can you please join in these chat room
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106068/security-privacy

Comment: we changed the code in `.htaccess` as you said but it is not working, can you suggest any other solution